# Decimal to Binary Conversion and vice-versa in Python

Tags: python, binary, decimal

1. Given a decimal number I need to convert it into binary
2. Given a binary number I need to convert it into decimal

After the conversion I need to perform some operation on it (for example, addition). Also I need print the result with a specified width.

To accomplish the above I wrote the following codes:

`Binary-Decimal:`

```
    n1 = int(input("Enter a binary number: "))
    n2 = int(input("Enter a binary number: "))

    # type cast to 'int' is done to provide width
    decimalN1 = int("{0:d}".format(n1), 2)
    decimalN2 = int("{0:d}".format(n2), 2)
    decimalSum = int("{0:d}".format(n1 + n2), 2)

    width = len(str(decimalSum))
    print("max width = {}".format(width))

    print ("{0:0{3}} + {1:0{3}} = {2:0{3}}".format(decimalN1, decimalN2, decimalSum, width))
    print ("{0} + {1} = {2}".format(type(decimalN1), type(decimalN2), type(decimalSum)))
```

`Decimal-Binary:`

```
    n1 = int(input("Enter a decimal number: "))
    n2 = int(input("Enter a decimal number: "))

    # type cast to 'int' is done to provide width
    binaryN1 = int("{0:b}".format(n1))
    binaryN2 = int("{0:b}".format(n2))
    binarySum = int("{0:b}".format(n1 + n2))

    width = (n1 + n2).bit_length()
    print("max width = {}".format(width))

    print ("{0:0{3}} + {1:0{3}} = {2:0{3}}".format(binaryN1, binaryN2, binarySum, width))
    print ("{0} + {1} = {2}".format(type(binaryN1), type(binaryN2), type(binarySum)))
```

What is want to know that is there any other (better) way of doing this? I know `bin()` function could be used, but then it returns a string, so I cannot perform (integer) operation on it.

Also any comments comments to improve the code will be much appreciated, as I am a beginner in Python.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. One obvious issue is that you ask the user for binary input and then immediately convert it to an integer *as decimal input*, which seems counterproductive.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be doing what I wanted to do. The following code is built upon my original code given in the question with suggestions from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151120/decimal-to-binary-conversion-and-vice-versa-in-python/151553#151553), as suggested.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# this function accepts a decimal integer and returns a binary string
def decimalToBinary (decimalInt) :
    return "{0:b}".format (decimalInt)
# this function accepts a binary string and returns a decimal integer
def binaryToDecimal (binaryString) :
    return int (binaryString, 2)

x = int (input ("Enter a decimal number: "))
y = int (input ("Enter a decimal number: "))
sumInDecimal = x + y
print ("{0} when converted to binary is {1}".format (x, decimalToBinary(x)))
print ("{0} when converted to binary is {1}".format (y, decimalToBinary(y)))
print ("Addition in base 10: \t {0} + {1} = {2}".format (x, y, x + y))
print ("Addition in base  2: \t {0} + {1} = {2}".format (decimalToBinary(x), decimalToBinary(y), decimalToBinary(sumInDecimal)))
print ()
x = input ("Enter a binary number: ")
y = input ("Enter a binary number: ")
# convert binary to decimal before any operation, the result of the operation will be in decimal
sumInDecimal = binaryToDecimal(x) + binaryToDecimal(y)
print ("{0} when converted to decimal is {1}".format (x, binaryToDecimal(x)))
print ("{0} when converted to decimal is {1}".format (y, binaryToDecimal(y)))
print ("Addition in base  2: \t {0} + {1} = {2}".format (x, y, decimalToBinary(sumInDecimal)))
print ("Addition in base 10: \t {0} + {1} = {2}".format (binaryToDecimal(x), binaryToDecimal(y), sumInDecimal))
```